# Как работает передача сервиса в метод?

Tags: php, symfony

Ниже пример рабочего кода, для получения значений, переданных методом POST.

Тут 2 варианта - `Request::createFromGlobals()` и `index1(Request $request): Response`.

В `Request::createFromGlobals()` я вижу явный вызов статического метода.

А в `index1(Request $request): Response` я вижу передачу объекта в метод, но я не вижу вызова метода с аргументом. Например `$index1_instance=new index1('объект Request');`

Мы просто создали метод с аргументом. Ничего явно туда не передали, но внутри работаем так, как будто передали объект типа Request.

Говорят, это называется передача сервиса в метод. Как это работает? Где и что вызывает метод?

```php
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request; // Пространство имен для получения данных методами GET и POST.


class TestController extends AbstractController
{
  #[Route('/test', name: 'home_page')]
  public function index(): Response
  {
    // Получаем ссылку на объект запроса/метода GET/POST/PUT/DELETE.
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

    // Пример получения данных с именем post_data, переданных методом POST.
    $postData = $request->request->get('post_data');
  }

  // Получаем $request из сервиса. 
  #[Route('/test1', name: 'home_page')]
  public function index1(Request $request): Response
  {
    // Пример получения данных с именем post_data, переданных методом POST.
    $postData = $request->request->get('post_data');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Фреймворк использует свою систему роутинга и маршрутизации, на основе MVC, где в роутах вы указываете контроллер и метод, а фреймворк в свою очередь наполняет Request данными и отправляет его туда, когда вы указали в роутах